# Нет перевода строки "did not earn this badge"

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, знаки

На странице подробного описания знака нет перевода, если знак ещё не получен:

---

[image: скрин дефекта]

---

Ещё интересно то, что знак-то я получил. Мне даже об этом сообщили:

---

### [image: знак-то я получил]

Но на странице описания знака мне говорится обратное.

Comment: У меня обычно, когда я получил какой-то знак, только на следующий день вся статистика обновляется.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Перевод применил:

- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/12401

Будет в новых сборках. Текущая 2023.10.6.43666

Относительно отображения, это может быть кэширование. В общем списке знаков он уже есть. На странице профиля пока рассинхрон:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]